# Salesforce datetime issues

Tags: c#, .net, api, datetime, salesforce

I am currently writing a c# .Net application that makes use of the salesforce API. I am sending account objects with datetime fields.

my datetime objects are all in this format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" which is also the same format of the date fields that is returned when I do a simple query "SELECT Name, Date FROM Account WHERE ID != null" - I have set a date in the a test account in salesforce manually prior to the query. I have checked everything that has to do with date format and I am confident that I am sending the correct datatype and datetime format to salesforce.

My problem is Salesforce seems to leave the Date field blank. Anyone know of a way I can make sure Salesforce is accepting the date details.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dtfi.FullDateTimePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
dtfi.DateSeparator = "/";
string _TempRangeEndDate = "2013-08-31"
DateTime objDateRangeEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(_TempRangeEndDate,dtfi);
_TempAccount.Date_End__c = objDateRangeStart; //Salesforce not accepting converted format which is "31/08/2013 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the .NET SOAP stack won't send dateTimes (and some other primative types like numbers) without you setting the additional speciified flag, e.g.

```
_TempAccount.Date_End__c = DateTime.Now;
_TempAccount.Date_End__c_Specified = True;
```

If you don't set this flag the .NET Soap stack doesn't serialize that element and its never sent to salesforce. (and so the field remains blank)

Answer (score 3):

> my datetime objects are all in this format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

No, they're not. At least not if you're talking about .NET `DateTime` values or database fields. Neither of those implicitly have formats - they're just values.

You should avoid using text *at all* when you don't need to. So when you send a query to SQL, you should use parameterized SQL with the `DateTime` values as parameters... no need for string conversions at all.

You say that Salesforce is "not accepting converted format which is "31/08/2013 00:00:00"" - but you're just assigning a `DateTime` value. That doesn't *have* a converted format. I think you need to look at your whole data flow carefully, and minimize string conversions. Where possible, stick to just using `DateTime`. Then check any errors from Salesforce *very carefully*. The problem may well not be what you think it is. (It's hard to tell as you haven't told us what sort of error Salesforce is giving you.)

Comment: Salesforce is not giving me any errors at all. my Application is not returning any errors from a CATCH. Salesforce just leaves the account field empty when I log in to check the newly created accounts. I am doing a conversion because the data I am collecting is from a database that stores its dates as "yyyy-MM-dd" which needs to be sent to saleforce into an account field with a DateTime datatype.

Comment: @user3214892: The database almost certainly stores its dates in some binary format, unless it's *really* a text field (which would be awful). But the heart of my answer is that a `DateTime` value doesn't have a format, so that's not the problem. You'll need to look elsewhere to work out why Salesforce isn't storing the data - it's not in the code you've shown, at least. (You haven't really provided enough description of what else is going on for us to help you pin it down more than that.)

Comment: Salesforce claims that you datetime needs to be in the same date format as what you see in your administrator account. I am trying to send a list of records from a database and send them to salesforce via their API as Salesforce Account Objects. An account object contains name, address etc. that those fields get populated without any problem - which are all String datatypes. My only problem is that the dateTime datatype is left blank even after putting it in the correct format that is advised by the Salesforce API documentation (about DateTime datatypes via API).

Comment: Even if I say _TempAccount.Date_End__c = DateTime.Now; Salesforce still leaves the field blank.

Comment: @user3214892: If this is a property of type `System.DateTime`, then it sounds like whoever wrote the documentation fundamentally doesn't understand what that type contains. That's worrying in itself... and you should probably get in touch with their support team.